# Has anyone tried setting up Kubernetes service endpoint on TFS 2015?

Tags: kubernetes, azure-devops, tfs-2015

Anyone triedsetting up Kubernetes service endpoint on TFS 2015 ? Tried https://github.com/TsuyoshiUshio/KubernetesTask this with VSTS , but this doesnt work on TFS 2015.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

[Kubernetes extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tsuyoshiushio.k8s-endpoint) task is NOT the official Kubernetes task created by Microsoft.

Based on my test, it's not supported on TFS 2015. It only works on TFS 2017+ and VSTS.

In TFS 2015, it can be installed and the `Kubernetes` appears under the services endpoint list, but nothing happens when select `Kubernetes` to create a new service endpoint.

So, if you insist on using this task, you can try upgrading to TFS 2017 or later version, or migrating to VSTS.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
Even I faced the same issue. I m planning to fork it and see if I could make it work on TF2015. Unfortunately we can't upgrade to VSTS till next quarter.

Comment: @user2153844 Have you resolved the issue? as starian mentioned in below answer, this is an known issue and not fixed yet with the extension. In my opinion, the simplest way is upgrading to TFS 2017.

Answer (score 0):

There is the error in Kubernetes extension if you are using TFS 2015, you can find the error in Console (Developer tool (F12):

```
Unable to get property '0' of undefined or null reference
TFS.Admin.ServiceEndpoints.Controls.js (4,4028)
```

The issue has been submitted on Github, you can track it:

[endpoint connection data not presented when trying to create a service endpoint](https://github.com/TsuyoshiUshio/KubernetesTask/issues/28)